# Conversion of a sequential model to a functional model with Keras 2.2.0

Tags: python, keras

Up to Keras version 2.1.6 one was able to "convert" a sequential model to a functional model by [accessing the underlying `model.model`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3190#issuecomment-231699656).
Since version 2.2.0 this is [no longer possible](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/3eab6103e0069d261c3e3586c12d5aaf0a331429/keras/engine/sequential.py#L112).

Can it still be done in some other way?

(In case you wonder why I would like to do something like this, I'm maintaining [a library](https://github.com/Dobiasd/frugally-deep) that relies on this conversion. :wink:)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I can't test this solution right now since I don't have Keras 2.2.0 installed, but I think it should work. Let's assume your sequential model is stored in `seqmodel`:

```py
from keras import layers, models

input_layer = layers.Input(batch_shape=seqmodel.layers[0].input_shape)
prev_layer = input_layer
for layer in seqmodel.layers:
    prev_layer = layer(prev_layer)

funcmodel = models.Model([input_layer], [prev_layer])
```

This should give the equivalent functional model. Let me know if I am mistaken.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works like a charm. I'll award your answer with the bounty as soon as SO allows it. :)

Comment: A small remark about a thing, I [just found out](https://github.com/Dobiasd/frugally-deep/issues/181#issuecomment-533775573): Before doing `prev_layer = layer(prev_layer)`, one should reset the inputs of this layer using `layer._inbound_nodes = []`. Otherwise a layer with previously only one inbound node now has two.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for conversion anymore because `Sequential` is now a subclass of `Model` hence it is already a model. Before it used to be a wrapper presumably that is why you are asking. From the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/ebdc1c8759f65768212b7e7113b5cae82e9df3d4/keras/engine/sequential.py#L24):

```py
class Sequential(Model):
  # ...
  @property
  def model(self):
    # Historically, `Sequential` was once
    # implemented as a wrapper for `Model` which maintained
    # its underlying `Model` as the `model` property.
    # We keep it for compatibility reasons.
    warnings.warn('`Sequential.model` is deprecated. '
                  '`Sequential` is a subclass of `Model`, you can '
                  'just use your `Sequential` instance directly.')
    return self
```

Whatever you can do with a model you can also do with `Sequential`, it only adds extra functionality like `.add` function for ease of use. You can just ignore those extra functions and use the object as if it's a functional model.

Comment: This should be the best answer.

Comment: Yes, from the point of view of the user this may be correct.

The [library that I maintain](https://github.com/Dobiasd/frugally-deep) however relies on the structure returned by `model.to_json()`. It can only process the functional structure, thus I need to convert sequential models to functional models.

This [code snippet](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/313ba6190290d75f469c5f8955723f93) and the [resulting output](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/38c2d439f2465b137a46814d5db578e0) demonstrate what I mean.

Comment: @DanielMöller @nuric When I first saw this question, I first checked the `model` property of `Sequential` in the source code and saw the comments that @nuric have mentioned in his/her answer. But I did an experiment with the `model` property in Keras 2.1.3 and saw the differences. For example, the result of conversion, the functional model, has an explicit `Input` layer, which is not in the sequential model (try `model.layers` or `model.summary`). Considering the fact that OP was developing a library based on Keras, I thought these differences matter to him/her more than an end-user of Keras.